# where exactly copy_to_user copies to?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I have a kernel call like this copy_to_user((void *) arg, &abc, sizeof(abc));
where abc is an integer with value 123.

I'm wondering on the kernel side, how do I get access to this value 123 that has been written to the user space?

I called my kernel function with ioctl(fd, FILE_OFFSET， &my_record);
after the kernel function returns, the value of my_record doesn't seem to change...

I've also tried to use read(fd, &a, sizeof(a)), but it still doesn't seem to give me the right value...

I know this question may be very very silly, but how would I read a value that has been copied to user space from the kernel in the user side?

oh, and one more thing is that I need to pass the arg from kernel and to kernel at the same time..does this affect the result as well?

Comment: Do an `ioctl` by passing the user space variable which you wanted to read in kernel. and do `copy_from_user` inside your `ioctl_write` routine in your kernel.

Comment: What is your point, is it that you have to pass data from user space to kernel space and using system call need to retrieve the data from kernel back to user space?